# Outlook 365 crashes while sharing Inbox to other user. MAPI C++

Tags: c++, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, mapi

I have Outlook plugin which is written to work with my server api. It's working perfectly fine with other outlook versions like Outlok 2016, 2019 and other versions.

For outlook 365 when I try to share Inbox by right click and selecting properties and then Sharing tab, click Add, select the existing user and click on Ok. It crashes Outlook and it gets restarted again.

While debugging my code I found that it gets exception somewhere inside msoutil.tli

```
inline HRESULT Olk::PropertyPageSite::OnStatusChange ( ) { 
    HRESULT _hr = raw_OnStatusChange();         // On this line it throws NULL PTR exception.
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this)); 
    return _hr; 
}
```

Any idea if it's known issue or anything I am missing here?

Comment: Do you get any problems without your add-in installed and running? Can you reproduce the issue with a newly created add-in? What customizations in your add-in lead to that issue?

Comment: But `raw_OnStatusChange` is your own function, right?

Comment: See the other discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73190229/outlook-propertypagesite-onstatuschange-crashes-outlook-with-an-accessviolatione