# Outlook PropertyPageSite OnStatusChange crashes outlook with an AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

**Context**

Since about a month, my Outlook addin has suddenly started crashing when changing properties using the C# `PropertyPageSite` object. It occurs when a text field in the property page changes and the `OnStatusChange` function of the `PropertyPageSite` object is called.

I downgraded outlook to a version from 2021 and the crash didn't occur, which most likely means the problem is occuring due to an update in Outlook.

The error I am getting is the following

```
System.AccessViolationException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

The first time I noticed the error was with Outlook version 2205. The application itself hasn't changed since the last time it worked.

**Code**

The following pieces of code are important.

The OptionPage class is declared like this

```
public partial class OptionPage : UserControl, Outlook.PropertyPage {
 ...
}
```

Registering a load event for the `PropertyPageSite` and the properties themselves from an external source.

```
public OptionPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Register for the Load event.
    this.Load += new EventHandler(OptionPage_Load);
}
```

The event handler for the load event

```
void OptionPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load our Settings here
    LoadOptions();

    // Get our Parent PropertyPageSite Object and store it into Classvariable.
    _PropertyPageSite = GetPropertyPageSite();
}
```

The way I grab the `PropertyPageSite` object which seems to be adviced by many forum threads. However, as far as I can tell, Microsoft doesn't have any information on how to get the object, except for when using visual basic.

```
Outlook.PropertyPageSite GetPropertyPageSite()
{
    Type type = typeof(System.Object);
    string assembly = type.Assembly.CodeBase.Replace("mscorlib.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll");
    assembly = assembly.Replace("file:///", "");

    string assemblyName = System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assembly).FullName;
    Type unsafeNativeMethods = Type.GetType(System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateQualifiedName(assemblyName, "System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods"));

    Type oleObj = unsafeNativeMethods.GetNestedType("IOleObject");
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo = oleObj.GetMethod("GetClientSite");
    object propertyPageSite = methodInfo.Invoke(this, null);

    return (Outlook.PropertyPageSite)propertyPageSite;
}
```

The dirtyness check called through event handlers when changing text fields

```
void OnDirty(bool isDirty)
{
    _Dirty = isDirty;

    // When this Method is called, the PageSite checks for Dirty Flag of all Optionspages.
    if (_PropertyPageSite != null)
    {
        _PropertyPageSite.OnStatusChange();
    }
}
```

**I have tried**

- Crash occurs in the following configurations in clean Windows VM's

  - Outlook 64 bit, outlook addin 64 bit
  - Outlook 32 bit, outlook addin 64 bit
  - Outlook 64 bit, outlook addin 32 bit
  - Outlook 23 bit, outlook addin 32 bit
- I downgraded outlook to a version from 2021 and the crash didn't occur, which most likely means the problem is occuring due to an update in Outlook
- I tried inspecting with WinDbg, but I do not have enough knowledge about it. I did add the results below from the assembly and stacktrace
- I installed older versions of my application that where working, but they have the same problem
- I tried to see if there is another way of getting the `PropertyPageSite` object or if the dll string replace was necessary, but I couldn't get it working any other way

**WinDbg results**

Stack trace

```
[0x0]   outlook!SmoothScroll + 0x33fa4   
[0x1]   outlook!OlkGetResourceHandle + 0xd77d   
[0x2]   outlook!StdCoCreateInstance + 0x9e630   
[0x3]   outlook!SmoothScroll + 0x34f3a   
[0x4]   outlook!StdCoCreateInstance + 0x3c047   
[0x5]   outlook!StdCoCreateInstance + 0x8bf7   
[0x6]   outlook!RefreshOutlookETWLoggingState + 0x782b   
[0x7]   0x7ffd28553c06   
[0x8]   MyOutlookAddin_28b66070000!MyOutlookAddin.OptionPage.OnDirty + 0x6d   
[0x9]   MyOutlookAddin_28b66070000!MyOutlookAddin.OptionPage.textBox_TextChanged + 0x55   
[0xa]   System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnTextChanged + 0x96    
....
```

Dissasembly. The error occurs on the last line

```
00007ff6`b3f47ba2 488b8f38020000 mov     rcx, qword ptr [rdi+238h]
00007ff6`b3f47ba9 48894de7       mov     qword ptr [rbp-19h], rcx
00007ff6`b3f47bad 4883c8ff       or      rax, 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh
00007ff6`b3f47bb1 48ffc0         inc     rax
00007ff6`b3f47bb4 66393441       cmp     word ptr [rcx+rax*2], si
```

**Versions**

- Outlook: 2206 build 16.0.15330.20260 64 bit
- .net: 4.5.2
- Visual c++ 2010 redistributable: 10.0.40219
- Visual studio 2010 tools for office runtime: 10.0.60724

What has changed that causes this behaviour?

**Edit 1**
[Requested procdump](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/99a22e5e29457c3918c9fe4abd92737220220802124111/e2700b)

**Edit 2**
[Requested TTD](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5646b369bd6fd3ccb66866f6992487d020220803070714/afaca7)

Comment: Can you collect a crash dump using ProcDump `procdump.exe -e -ma -o -w outlook.exe` and make it available?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I put the procdump in the description

Comment: received, thanks. Any chance you can create a time travel debug log? (see https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/09/27/time-travel-debugging-now-available-windbg-preview/)

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko the run file has been added

Comment: it looks like the crash has not been captured. Did it occur while the TTD was being collected?

Comment: Also, is there a chance you can create a sample addin that exhibits the problem? Microsoft devs can see the crash in the first dump, but the its location and the registers don't seem to make sense.

Comment: Microsoft Development was able to reproduce the problem and is working on a fix. No ETA yet.

Comment: Thank you @DmitryStreblechenko. I assum the crash reproduction in TDD is not necassary anymore?

While making the TDD, I could click a million times on the Go button in WinDbg, but the debugger would keep on breaking on the exact same line. After loads of clicks I gave up and hoped it was enough. Outlook never actually crashed because WinDbg wouldn't let it.

Is there a Microsoft ticket where I can keep an eye on the progression?

Comment: Yes, they have a reproducible case. There is no public ticket you can view.

Comment: Then I will be eagerly awaiting the fix. Thank you for your help and research so far.

Comment: It looks like the fix is already being pushed. Try to download updates and install Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an Outlook bug an it has been fixed by Microsoft.

See comments